# Low Search - Only One Channel - How

Tags: low-search, low

I've got a search form using Low Search where I want to restrict results to only one specific channel. I've created a collection called "galleries" and a shortcut called "galleries" and this code below:

```
{exp:low_search:form 
    result_page="/search/results" 
    required="keywords"
    form_class="form-inline"
    shortcut="galleries"
    }
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="keywords" class="sr-only">Search our Colorado Trips</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keywords" name="keywords" placeholder="Search our Galleries">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

But no matter what I do the results page shows results for all channels not just the Galleries channel

Answer (score 1):

Low provided a solution to me on the EE slack channel.

All I needed to do was add a hidden field with the collection name or id as the value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="collection" value="4">
```